# Converting div block that includes sag d3 chart into the image throws an error Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js, ecmascript-6

Converting div block that includes sag d3 chart into the image throws an error Extra content at the end of the document

```
 SVG2PNG() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); // Create a Canvas element.
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // For Canvas returns 2D graphic.
  //var data = svg.outerHTML; // Get SVG element as HTML code.
    var svg = document.querySelector('.chart-root').innerHTML;
   console.log(svg)
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg);
  canvas.width = 300,
  canvas.height = 500
  img.onload = function() {
    canvas
            .getContext('2d')
            .drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
  console.log(img.src)
  //return await canvg(canvas, data); // Render SVG on Canvas.

},
```

I am using above method for converting a block that includes d3 chart inside it (which is an SVG) into image however when I click the link in the console from img.src it throws an error `Extra content at the end of the document`  What is wrong and how can I fix this conversion problem and convert it into the image properly for passing it in the PDF later

Comment: Are you sure your `chart-root` element contains only an `<svg>` element? Also, have you taken a look at the contents of the `svg` text? Note that `.innerHTML` isn't guaranteed to return XML.

Comment: No it includes other elements as well besides svg.SVG is a d3 chart. Then how can I fix it instead of innerHtml?

Comment: If your `chart-root` element contains something other than an `<svg>` element, then the `innerHTML` of the `chart-root` element will contain these other elements, and in particular it will have multiple elements and so not be well-formed XML. Your code contains what looks to be a commented-out attempt to use `svg.outerHTML`: what happened when you tried that?